# Convert string to formula

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Hope you can help with af old classic ASP problem.

In my database i got a TEXT string with this value: `(X*5)/25`

```vb
strCalString = (X*5)/25
strX = 100
strOutput = replace(strCalString,"X",strX)
```

Then is my output: `(100*5)/25`
But i want to have my output to be: `20`, and not my formula string,

How can i do this, to get it to work.

i have tried to convert my `strOutput` to `cint(strOutput)`, but thats not working. 
And search on google, i could find anything.

Comment: @Lankymart no need to add the language hint, the question is already tagged as vbscript so the default behavior is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the VBScript `Eval()` function:

```
strCalString = "(X*5)/25"
strX = 100
strOutput = Replace(strCalString, "X", strX)
strResult = Eval(strOutput)
```